# Resultset Mapping Returns null, SQL statement doesn't

Tags: java, resultset, sqlresultsetmapping

I have an SQL statement like this:

```
SELECT generatedresult,sum(size) as count  FROM table1_detail AS w WHERE date > '2011.06.01' AND w.l_date < '2011.06.02'  GROUP BY category ORDER BY count  desc ;
```

Which returns:

```
generatedresult  |   count    
------------------+------------
                  | 3743040708
 Phrase1          |    1332377
 Phrase2          |          0
 Phrase3          |          0
```

When I write a resultset mapping for this query like this:

```
@Entity
@Stateless
@Cache(type = CacheType.NONE, alwaysRefresh=true, shared=false, expiry=1, size=0)
@Cacheable(false)
@SqlResultSetMappings({
    @SqlResultSetMapping(name = "ResultMapping",
    entities = {
        @EntityResult(entityClass = ResultMap.class,
        fields = {
            @FieldResult(name = "generatedresult", column = "generatedresult"),
            @FieldResult(name = "count", column = "count")
        })})
})
```

and use it in another class I got null result. Does anyone having any opinion about this issue?

Comment: I'll take a wild guess, since I don't really know all that much about resultset mapping. But it seems from your SQL that you select the sum AS count, but in the mapping you are actually looking for a column called count.

Comment: Hi, that is how it is used in resultmapping. You can name a column in the sql as you like and than call it that way in the resultmapping. Anyway, thanks for your comment.